# Having trouble coding procedures and parameters in order to get the desired output

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

This program is to automate the selection of  the wardrobe for the day based on a color selection.  The database will contain garments of 4 different colors and will ensure that the garment that’s been clean the longest will be selected.  The system will track when a garment is selected for use and also when it has been cleaned and returned to the closet.

I have created the tables. I am having trouble figuring out how to structure my code in order to gain the desired output.

Package Procedure requirements:
 Daily garment selection

o Parameters
 Date
 Color

o Process
 Select one shirt, sweater, pants, socks and underwear that has a last transaction
of cleaned and put away and has been put away the longest
 The garment must match the color request with the exception of underwear
which will not require a color match
 Write a a transaction for each garment selected indicating that has been
selected for use

o Output:
 Garment Selection records for the day

 Garment transaction process

o Parameters
 Garment Id

o Process
 Write a cleaned and put away transaction for the garment as of today

Extra Credit
Identify table/process changes that would make the selection more efficient.

Here is the data:
[Excel sheet with garment clean/dirty status and date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chwHd.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you have questions about why **the code which you have written** doesn't work please edit your question to include the code, along with an explanation of what's wrong (such as "I expected XYZ but the code produced ABC"), and perhaps someone can help you.

Comment: Questions like this would require folks to do a lot of work to answer. I'm assuming you've converted the spreadsheet data into two tables no? Why not share with us the SQL to create the tables and insert the sample data? Also, it seems you've taken a shot at writing the package and haven't had much luck. Why not provide us with the code and a description of what isn't working so we know where to look? This would go a long way in getting help.